# Field error in object 'exchange' on field 'initAmount': rejected value

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a problem with Spring validation mechanism. I have entity class User (I skipped getter and setter methods):

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_details_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Log> logs;

    public User() {}

    public User(@NotEmpty String email, @NotEmpty String password, UserDetails userDetails) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }

}
```

Validation classes and enums:

```
import com.example.demo.entities.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;


@Component
public class UserValidator extends MyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return User.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;

        validate(ValidatorEnum.EMAIL, user.getEmail(), "email", errors);
        validate(ValidatorEnum.PASSWORD, user.getPassword(), "password", errors);
//        validate(ValidatorEnum.USERNAME, user.getUserDetails().getName(), "username", errors);

    }
}


import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public abstract class MyValidator {
    protected void validate(ValidatorEnum validatorEnum, String value, String field, Errors errors){

        String patternReg = validatorEnum.getPattern();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternReg);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

        if(!matcher.matches())
            errors.rejectValue(field, validatorEnum.getErrCode(), validatorEnum.getErrMessage());
    }
}


public enum ValidatorEnum {


    USERNAME("[a-zA-z]{2,}", "err_code", "The text should contain a minimum of 3 characters"),
    PASSWORD("[a-zA-z]{5,}","err_code", "The text should contain a minimum of 6 characters"),
    EMAIL("^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&�*+/=?`{|}~^.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$", "err_code", "Email format required"),
    AMOUNT("[0-9]*.[0-9]*", "err_code", "Wrong cash value"),
    CURRENCY("[A-Z]{3}", "err_code", "Wrong currency value");

    private String pattern;
    private String errCode;
    private String errMessage;

    ValidatorEnum(String pattern, String errCode, String errMessage) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.errCode = errCode;
        this.errMessage = errMessage;
    }
}
```

and registration .jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user">

    <%--        <label>Username</label>--%>
    <%--        <form:input path="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>--%>
    <%--        <form:errors path="username"/>--%>

    <label>email</label>
    <form:input path="email" placeholder="Email" type="text"/>
<%--    <form:errors path="email"/>--%>
    <label>Password</label>
    <form:input path="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
    <form:errors path="password"/>
    <label>Username</label>
    <form:input path="userDetails.name" placeholder="username" type="text"/>
    <%--        <form:errors path="userDetails.username"/>--%>
    <label>Surname</label>
    <form:input path="userDetails.surname" placeholder="surname" type="text"/>
    <form:errors path="userDetails.surname"/>
    <form:button type="submit">
        Register
    </form:button>


</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And everything with this works correctly. Error messages are displayed in form:errors tags. But I wanted to do cash validation too (after typing cash amount, i store it in a buffer as a String type (to pass it to BigDecimal object after validation)). Buffer class:

```
public class ExchangeCalculatorBuffer {

    private String initAmount;
    private String initCurrency;
    private String targetCurrency;

    public ExchangeCalculatorBuffer(String initAmount, String initCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
        this.initAmount = initAmount;
        this.initCurrency = initCurrency;
        this.targetCurrency = targetCurrency;
    }
}
```

Validator class:

```
import com.example.demo.financialSystem.ExchangeCalculatorBuffer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class CashValidator extends MyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return ExchangeCalculatorBuffer.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        ExchangeCalculatorBuffer exchangeCalculatorBuffer = (ExchangeCalculatorBuffer) o;


        validate(ValidatorEnum.AMOUNT, exchangeCalculatorBuffer.getInitAmount(), "initAmount", errors);
        validate(ValidatorEnum.CURRENCY, exchangeCalculatorBuffer.getInitCurrency(), "initCurrency", errors);
        validate(ValidatorEnum.CURRENCY, exchangeCalculatorBuffer.getTargetCurrency(), "targetCurrency", errors);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Controller
public class ExchangeController {

    private final JsonManager<String, BigDecimal> jsonManager;
    private final CashValidator validator;

    @Autowired
    public ExchangeController(JsonManager<String, BigDecimal> jsonManager, CashValidator validator) {
        this.jsonManager = jsonManager;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder){
        webDataBinder.addValidators(validator);
    }

    @PostMapping("/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public CashAmountWithCurrency getExchange(@ModelAttribute("exchange") Calculator<String, BigDecimal> exchangeCalculator){
        return exchangeCalculator.count(jsonManager.getMap());
    }

    @PostMapping("/count")
    public String count(final @ModelAttribute("exchange") @Valid ExchangeCalculatorBuffer exchangeCalculatorBuffer, Model model, BindingResult result){

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        ExchangeCalculator exchangeCalculator = new ExchangeCalculator(
                new CashAmountWithCurrency(exchangeCalculatorBuffer.getInitAmount(), exchangeCalculatorBuffer.getInitCurrency()),
                new CashAmountWithCurrency("1.0000", exchangeCalculatorBuffer.getTargetCurrency())
        );
        model.addAttribute("result", "result: "+exchangeCalculator.count(jsonManager.getMap()));
        model.addAttribute("exchange", new ExchangeCalculatorBuffer());
        model.addAttribute("rates", jsonManager.getKeys());

        return "home";
    }
}
```

.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
<%--    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/src/main/webapp/js/angular/script.js"></script>--%>
<%--    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">--%>
</head>
<body>

<a>
    Hello ${loggedUser.userDetails.name} ${loggedUser.userDetails.surname}
</a>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="exchange" action="count">
    <form:input type="text" path="initAmount"/>
    <form:errors path="initAmount"/>
    <a>
        From:
    </a>
    <form:select path="initCurrency">
        <c:forEach items="${rates}" var="item">
            <form:option value="${item}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>

    <a>
        to:
    </a>
    <form:select path="targetCurrency">
        <c:forEach items="${rates}" var="item">
            <form:option value="${item}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
    <form:button type="submit">count</form:button>
</form:form>

${result}
${message}

<a href="logout">
    Logout
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And after typing amount as a char set (for example: "test") I get the Whitelabel error Page, instead of my home page with marked errors. I don't understand why. I've done it almost the same way as user validation. Please write a comment if I forgot about any necessery class. Thank you!

Whitelabel error page:

**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Feb 26 18:34:40 CET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='exchange'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'exchange' on field 'initAmount': rejected value [test]; codes [err_code.exchange.initAmount,err_code.initAmount,err_code.java.lang.String,err_code]; arguments []; default message [Wrong cash value]